# Remove specific unicode character in the string in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

I am trying to remove specific unicode character in my string.
Say we have below code .

```
public static string RemoveVerticalLine(this string source, char nil = ' ')
        {
            var s = '\u+007C';
            return new string(source.Select(c => c == s ? nil : c).ToArray());
        }
```

In the sample. I tried to remove the U+007c(Vertical Line). But I don't know why VS tell me error `too many characters in character literal`. Did I missed something?

[image]

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't how C# escape sequences work.

You need to write `'\u007c'`.

Or just use the actual character: `'|'`.

Comment: what does it mean `+` ? why need to remove it ?

Comment: @Joe.wang: That's just the convention used when talking about Unicode code points. It has nothing to do with C# syntax. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences

Comment: Got it . Convention for the Unicode code point in c#, Thanks.